# How does void* work as a universal reference type?

Tags: c++, c, types

From Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott

> For systems programming, or to facilitate the writing of
>   general-purpose con- tainer (collection) objects (lists, stacks,
>   queues, sets, etc.) that hold references to other objects, several
>   languages provide a universal reference type. **In C and C++, this
>   type is called void ***. In Clu it is called any; in Modula-2,
>   address; in Modula-3, refany; in Java, Object; in C#, object.

In C and C++, how does `void *` work as a universal reference type?

`void *` is always only a pointer type, while a universal reference type contains all values, both pointers and nonpointers. So I can't see how `void *` is a universal reference type.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it work", specifically?

Comment: `void *` is always a pointer type, while a universal reference type contains all values, both pointers and nonpointers

Comment: It can point to anything.  But, you have to tell the compiler what it is before you can actually get to what it points to.

Comment: Pointers are the closest you can get to a reference-like concept in C.

Comment: ***In C and C++, how does void * work as a universal reference type?*** I say it does not. It works as a universal pointer. However to dereference you need to cast.

Comment: I wouldn't use the words "universal reference", these belong to Scott Myers  now and have a different meaning. I would use "opaque references" instead, because the meaning of the value is known to the class that "owns" the data.

Comment: @RustyX: "*I wouldn't use the words "universal reference", these belong to Scott Myers now and have a different meaning.*" No, they don't. Those are called "forwarding references".

Comment: C **or** C++, pick one. You can't meaningfully talk about "references" in a way that makes sense for both languages (unless you simply say C doesn't have them at all).

Comment: @Leushenko The quote from the book makes it clear that "reference" here is the general computer science term, and not C++ references specifically.

Comment: A pointer to a function may not fit in a `void*`.  `void*`, in C is **not** a universal reference type nor universal pointer type.

Comment: In C++, you use templates, not containers of void pointers. Tagging this as C++ and C makes the question meaningless. I have removed the C++ tag.

Comment: Note that the excerpt states that a universal reference type can *reference* any object, not that it can *contain* any object. So while a `void *` might not be able to *contain* a `uint128_t`, it can still *reference* (or point to) it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Since the text quoted in the question specifically refers to both C and C++ in the same breath, I think this is one of the rare cases where it _is_ appropriate to tag with both, but answerers should be careful to address both languages.

Comment: @zwol Anyone is at liberty to retag it.

Answer (score 8):

A `void*` pointer will generally hold any pointer that is not a C++ pointer-to-member. It's rather inconvenient in practice, since you need to cast it to another pointer type before you can use it. You also need to convert it to the same pointer type that it was converted *from* to make the `void*`, otherwise you risk undefined behavior.

A good example would be the [`qsort` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). It takes a `void*` pointer as a parameter, meaning it can point to an array of anything. The comparison function you pass to `qsort` must know how to cast two `void*` pointers back to the types of the array elements in order to compare them.

Comment: "A `void*` pointer will generally hold any pointer ..."  --> A `void*` may be insufficient to "hold" a function pointer.  I agree with [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846121/how-does-void-work-as-a-universal-reference-type#comment78650980_45846249) that an attempt to save a function pointer in a `void*` is UB.

Comment: @chux - It's UB I believe.

Comment: Very, very slight nitpick (if I'm right) on "*You also need to convert it to the same pointer type that it was converted from*", **before you use it**. I think you can covert to any pointer type you like in the mean time. Though, I think that's more language-layer level than anything practical.

Comment: @chux UB per the letter of the standard, but required to "work as expected" by both POSIX and the de-facto Windows ABI.

Comment: @luk32 If you don't convert it to either a type compatible with the one you started with, or a character type, before dereferencing, you have UB because of the pointer-aliasing rules.

Comment: @zwol Aren't the conversions allowed, but using the result is an UB? My bad then.

Comment: @luk32 Er, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @zwol I think not only deference might be illegal, but using result as a parameter also, for e.g. `memcpy` I am not sure though. I was thinking about aliasing too. We obviously agree on dereferencing. That's what I meant by language-lawyer level thing. Cheers.

Comment: @chux can you expand on the restriction for function pointers? The only oddity I remember is long pointers on the segmented x86 architecture.

Comment: @zwol a compatible type might not be good enough. You'll get in trouble with multiply derived classes, since pointers to the base classes won't all have the same address. The compiler needs type information to properly adjust the pointer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I only know the rules for this in C, which doesn't have multiply derived anything.  C++ will be _similar_, but undoubtedly not the same. (Also, I mean "compatible" in the sense precisely defined by the C standard, which is a lot closer to "exactly the same" than most people realize.)

Comment: @zwol originally the question was tagged with both C and C++. It looks like C++ was removed, so some of my answer and comments won't make sense. I can see that C might not have the same problem with compatible types.

Comment: @MarkRansom Your memory of segmented x86 architecture is an example of a possible wide function pointer (e.g. 32-bit) and a narrow `void*` (e.g. 16-bit) .  IAC, C (§6.3 ...) specifies conversion to/from _object_ pointers with `void*` and by omission, conversion to/from function pointers is UB.  A function pointer of one type converts to/from a function pointer of another type.  So `union { void *v; int (*f)(); }` is close to a universal "ref" type.

Answer (score 4):

The crux of your confusion is that neither an instance of `void *` nor an instance of Modula-3's `refany`, nor an instance of any other language's "can refer to anything" type, *contains* the object that it refers to.  A variable of type `void *` is always a pointer and a variable of type `refany` is always a reference.  But the *object that they refer to* can be of any type.

A purist of programming-language theory would tell you that C does not have references at all, because pointers are not references.  It has a nearly-universal *pointer* type, `void *`, which can point to an *object* of any type (including integers, aggregates, and other pointers).  As a common but not ubiquitous extension, it can also point to any function (functions are not objects).

The purist would also tell you that C++ does *not* have a (nearly-)universal pointer type, because of its stricter type system, and doesn't have a universal reference type either.

They would also say that the book you are reading is being sloppy with its terminology, and they would caution you to not take any one such book for the gospel truth on terminological matters, or any other matters.  You should instead read widely in both books and CS journals and conference proceedings (collectively known as "the literature") until you gain an "ear" for what is generally-agreed-on terminology, what is specific to a subdiscipline or a community of practice, and so on.

And finally they would remind you that C and C++ are two different languages, and anyone who speaks of them in the same breath is either glossing over the distinctions (which may or may not be relevant in context), decades out of date, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason is that you can take address of any variable of any type and cast it to `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

It does by a silent contract that you know the actual type of object.

So you can store different kinds of elements in a container, but you need to somehow know what is what when taking elements back, to interpret them correctly.

The only convenience `void*` offers is that it's idiomatic for this, i.e. it's clear that dereferencing the pointer makes no sense, and `void*` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type. That is for c/

In c++ this is called type erasure techniques preferred. Or special types, like [`any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any) (there is a boost version of this too.)

Comment: Not in C++. This question makes no sense if it is tagged as both C and C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've edited in a supplement/clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is no more **just a pointer**. Thus, it **holds** an address of an object (or an array and stuffs like that)

When your program is running, every variable should have it owns address in memory, right? And pointer is somethings point to that address.

In normal, each type of pointer should be the same type of object `int b = 5; int* p = &b;` for example. But that is the case you know what the type is, it means the `specific type`.

But sometimes, you just want to know that it stores somethings somewhere in memory and you know what "type" of that address, you can cast easily. For example, in OpenCV library which I am learning, there are a lot of functions where user can pass the arguments to instead of declaring global variables and most use in `callback` functions, like this:
`void onChange(int v, void *ptr)`
Here, the library does not care about what `ptr` point to, it just know that when you call the function, if you pass an address to like this `onChange(5,&b)` then you must cast `ptr` to the same type before dealing with it `int b = static_cast<int*>(ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably this explanation from  [Understanding pointers from Richard Reese](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028000.do)  will help

> A pointer to void is a general-purpose pointer used to hold references to any data type.

It has two interesting properties:

- A pointer to void will have the same representation and memory alignment as a pointer to char
- A pointer to void will never be equal to another pointer. However, two void pointers assigned a NULL  value will be equal.

Any pointer can be assigned to a pointer to void. It can then be cast back to its original pointer type. When this happens the value will be equal to the original pointer value.

This  is  illustrated  in  the  following  sequence,  where  a  pointer  to 
int   is  assigned  to  a pointer to void and then back to a pointer to int

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num = 100;
    int *pi = &num;

    printf("value of pi is %p\n", pi);

    void* pv = pi;
    pi = (int*)pv;

    printf("value of pi is %p\n", pi);
}
```

Pointers to void are used for data pointers, not function pointers

Comment: "A pointer to void will never be equal to another pointer" - is that true?

Comment: `"%p"` matches a `void *`, not an `int *` as in this example code.  `printf("value of pi is %p\n", pi);` is UB, even though it commonly "works".