# Given that void is an empty type, why is void* a pointer type which can point to an object of any type?

Tags: c

In C, `void` is a type without any value, i.e. an empty type.

Following that meaning of `void`, `void*` should be a pointer pointing to nothing, while on the contrary, `void*` is actually a pointer type which can point to an object of any type.

Do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Because the C standard says so.

Comment: The rules about `void` and `void *` are special cases.  `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.  A `void *` is a pointer to an indeterminate type.  You can't use it directly to dereference the data; you have to convert it to a pointer to a complete type before you can do that.

Comment: What would you call it?

Comment: I don't think there needs to be any real logic behind this: the creators deemed a general pointer type handy, so they chose `void*` because it resembles the purpose the most.

Comment: Pointing to nothing is very well done by `NULL`. Dedicating a whole type to it would be wasteful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011911/3140

Comment: In the beginning was the earth, and the earth was without form, and `void *`. I'll show myself out.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846121/how-does-void-work-as-a-universal-reference-type

Comment: What's your obsession with generic questions? Do you really want to know all this or just collecting upvotes?

Comment: There's a pressure to keep the amount of keywords in a language to a minimum in order to prevent collisions with libraries.

You could certainly introduce an `any` keyword and declare that it may only be used to create pointers, but that's rather wasteful when you can, without much loss of clarity, simply reuse the `void` type.

Comment: @RustyX Whoa, careful there. Some people are curious, no need to accuse them of something you have no evidence of here.

Comment: Remember that C is a very low-level language. Even the concept of "type" is a fairly high-level one. In C, pointers (all of them. typed and void) are generally nothing but memory addresses. Type information helps the compiler fetch different kinds of info from the address, but the variable itself is nothing more or less than a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than "a pointer to an object of any type", you could think of a `void *` as "a pointer to something for which we don't know the type." It's basically a pointer without any type information associated with it, and the `void` can signify that lack of a type.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not need all the information about a type in order to assign pointers to each other, nor does it need any information to define a structure member or to pass such pointer as a parameter to a function, the reason is probably clear, all pointers have the same size.

When the program attempts to read from or write to the underlying data — the data the pointer actually points to, then it needs all the type's information in order to perform *pointer arithmetic*. So it basically needs to know what is the offset to a member of a structure the pointer points to, or where exactly is `ptr[3]` when you need to dereference it. It needs the information necessary to compute such offsets.

Since the compiler does not really need the type of a pointer for the mentioned operations, the pointer can have no type, so `void *` is the "*type*" of such pointer. But note, that you will need an actual type before you can do anything useful with it.